# Visual studio "Dereferencing NULL pointer" warning

Tags: c, memory, sal

I have a function that creates an address, stores values at the address contiguously, and then returns the address:

```
double* quadratic(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double* solAddr = malloc((size_t)(2 * sizeof(double)));

    *(solAddr) = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c)) / 2.0 * a;
    *(solAddr + 1) = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c)) / 2.0 * a;

    return solAddr;
}
```

However, I'm getting a warning that states `Warning   C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'solAddr'`. After some online searching, I found that I simply need to make sure `solAddr` is not `NULL` with an "if"- statement and the warning disappears:

```
double* quadratic(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double* solAddr = malloc((size_t)(2 * sizeof(double)));

    if (solAddr != NULL)
    {
        *(solAddr) = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c)) / 2.0 * a;
        *(solAddr + 1) = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c)) / 2.0 * a;
    }

    return solAddr;
}
```

Does the warning really mean that `solAddr` *may* be `NULL`? It seems that the text states otherwise. The code works both with and without the `NULL` check but I'm confused as to what this warning is really trying to tell me.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-160): *This warning indicates that your code dereferences a potentially null pointer.*

Comment: Well, that solves it then. I should probably read the docs before anything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SeanXie "*Does the warning really mean that solAddr may be NULL*" Yes, that's how [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) indicates failure. If your "*text states otherwise*" then that text is either incomplete or plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that warning is there because `malloc` could return `NULL` if allocation failed.

It's actually a warning from [SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=msvc-160) annotations applied to the library headers, not Visual Studio itself. You should always check `malloc` return value for `NULL` and handle it, because `malloc` *could* return `NULL` if it fails. My usual method is:

```
   space = malloc(SIZE);
   if(NULL == space)
   {
       goto cleanup;
   }

   use(space);

cleanup:
   free(space);
   space = NULL;
```